# Any disadvantage of inheriting from boost::noncopyable vs delete copy ctor and op?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, delete-operator, noncopyable

First:

```
class T1 : boost::noncopyable {
    // ...
}
```

Second:

```
class T2 {
public:
    T2(const T2&) = delete;
    T2& operator=(const T2&) = delete;
}
```

Are they the same? What are disadvantages of each? I mean runtime costs, not comfort of writing code or readability.

In 2016 with C++11/14 is there any advantage to use `boost::noncopyable` instead of C++11 `= delete`?